# GDB how to set watchpoint from file offset?

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

So I'm reverse engineering a binary with a hex editor and gdb, the executable has no debugging information for me to work with. How do I set a watchpoint at a given offset in the binary I'm running?

For example:

In the executable file there is a byte at offset 0x85c6d and I want to set a watchpoint there. How would I do this in gdb? Is it possible?

I've already tried `watch 0x85c6d` and `watch *0x85c6d` but the first one didn't work at all and the second one set an offset for the ram instead of the actual file. I've looked through the [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) for watchpoints to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes: you need to figure out where *in memory* this address will end up, and set a watchpoint on that memory location.

If this is an ELF binary, `readelf -l a.out` will tell you which parts of the file are loaded at what address (you care about the `LOAD` segments).

For example:

```
readelf -Wl a.out | grep LOAD
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x000638 0x000638 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e48 0x0000000000600e48 0x0000000000600e48 0x0001e0 0x0001e8 RW  0x200000
```

This tells you that executable code starting from offset 0 in the file will be loaded in memory at address `0x400000`, and data from offset `0xe48` will be loaded in memory at `0x600e48`.

Things are a bit more complicated for PIE binaries: you'll need to add initial load address, which can change from execution to execution. The good news: GDB by default disables randomization, so the initial load address will not vary from run to run while the program runs under GDB.

You can find the initial load address using `(gdb) info proc map` command.